# Error: warning: No mobile provisioning file provided

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I was trying to use applesign on a personal app.

`applesign -i 1695CB418CE88EF8B473E474F364F5E4B18CAE0F SecureStorev1.ipa`

But I'm receiving the error

`No mobile provisioning file provided     at Applesign.signAppDirectoryInternal (/Users/User/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/applesign/index.js:167:15)`

Any idea on the fix for this?

I'm trying to install an app to a jailbroken iphone via xcode. I watched a video where the command I used worked, but it isn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this. I had to add the following.

```
-b [bundle identifier]
-c [Followed by file]
-m [embedded mobile provision file]
```

The final format ended up being.

```
applesign -i [my string] -b [bundle identifier] -c [application] -m
[embedded.mobileprovision]
```

Just thought I'd leave the answer here to help out anyone else who may be having this issue.